# List style set to none has no effect

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have...

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

.. on my ul, and the dot is still there.

As you can see from Chrome inspector, it's the top most style...

[image]

Any ideas why this would not work as it normally does?

I'm creating the list using react...

```
class Shift extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <li>
               ...
            </li>
        );
    }
};

class CommentList extends React.Component {

    render() {

        var nodes = this.props.data.map(function (s) {

            return (
                <Shift key={s.sid} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
                {nodes}
            </ul>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: add your html/css complete code

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or something demonstrating it. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mrmills/0pb5jLx5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a different CSS file, I had...

```
ul li:before {
   content: '\2022 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0';
}
```

So this wasn't overriding list-style, but it broke it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
list-style-type: none;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

"list-style" is the shorthand, where you need to add the other values too, in your case you could do

```
list-style: none outside none;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to set that as `list-style: none;` works on other sites. The `type` version doesn't work anyhow - by itself or with what I currently have.

Comment: unless you add an inspectable example we can only guess

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I elected to use `divs` instead.

Comment: I figured I'd save my energy for the next utterly basic thing that doesn't work, which, funnily enough, I'm working on right now!

Comment: if a no-brainer css-thing doesn't work for me, it's often a weird space-character in the css, when I accidentally pressed cmd + space. you could also try with !important. just weird that your browser is showing the styles correctly in the inspector.

Comment: Precisely! Yes, I've tried `!important`. I've tried setting the style using the inspector too. My suspicion is that React is blocking it in someway. It might be interesting to get to the bottom of it. I will come back if I get round to it.

Comment: I had this in a different CSS file... 'ul li:before {
            content: '\2022 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0';
        }'

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ul, li {
     list-style: none !important;
}
```

This makes sure that we target both the ul and the li tags with the `!important` making it important so we don't overrule it with other styles.